# In phonegap On adding a new plugin if I rebuild my app it is removing the total project and creating a new one

Tags: android, cordova

Im trying to add a new plugin in phonegap,  in order to work a new plugin we should rebuild the app. But if i rebuild the app my entire project is removed and it is creating a new one.

how can i use the plugin without rebuild or how can i rebuild app without loosing my code.

Im trying to add the splashscreen plugin.

Comment: what do you mean by 'removed' and ' creating a new one'

Comment: offcourse you need to build everytime even if you add a fullstop in it.

Comment: My javascript files and html files which i created are get removed . When we create a fresh app what the files will come, only those are showing.

Comment: the build you are saying to run it on a emulator. but if we add a new plugin then we need to do rebuild in the nodejs cmd prompt.

Comment: you are doing something terribly wrong. show you file structure before and after building your app

Comment: **cordova rebuild** is the command i used after adding the plugin. it is building the app again like all the default files which will come after creating a new project like wise  it is showing. I got this problem while doing my testing project. so that i didnt applied it now..

Comment: use corodva build command

Comment: All the files which are in my www folder is removed and only default files like index.html, index.js are present

Comment: which platform folder you are checking / building ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all: I would recommend you to get a deeper look into Cordova. Therefore you need to read the [Cordova Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/).

The reason for just having a clear index and things like that is, that the command `cordova build` will copy all files from the root www folder into your platforms. That means, that you probably have worked in the www folders from your platforms.

Your folder structure is sth like this
[image]

So if you run the cordova build command it will copy all files from the www folder (2.) in your folders for your platforms (1.). If you now have not worked in the root www folder, it'll just copy the files which were created while you build the project the first time.

Normaly the Plugins you installed are available directly after you installed them - without a rebuild. So i would first recommend you to update your cordova (`npm update -g cordova`). After that you should create a new project and copy your files from your last project into the root www folder. A workflow for that should look like follows:

1. `cordova create testProject com.example.com testProject`
2. `cd testProject`
3. `cordova platform add [platform you need]`
4. `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` [plugins you need] - please note: Since Cordova is on V5, all Plugins are available via npm so the new command for installing plugins looks like: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen`.
5. After you added all now you're copying the index and css file from your project into your new www root folder
6. Now you run `cordova build`

If you want an extra plugin now, which you have not installed when you created your project, you close all files your IDE (Xcode or Android Studio) and then move into your project with your terminal/console. There you can add a plugin now and it should be available after it is installed with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-*` **without** the build command!

Hope that helped you, let me know if you need further information!

Comment: Thankyou Sithys and Murtaza. After creating the app , if i want to add a plugin im doing plugin add and then cordova build.. Now I got that no need  of building the app if we want to add a plugin after the app is created.

Comment: Correct, you got it ;-)!